# This appears when the device is booting

Tags: boot, shutdown

This appears when the device is booting. What is the solution? I also have another problem: when I shut down the device, it opens again. If I solve these codes, will the problem be solved?

[image: boot-error]

Comment: You may need to update your BIOS or your firmware. For the BIOS, try to find out if your particular hardware vendor has an update available. For the firmware, try `sudo fwupdmgr update`. Both may or may not solve your problem though.